# Why is the complexity O(n)?

Tags: arrays, time-complexity

This is a program used to find the largest sum of contiguous subarray within a one-dimensional array of numbers.

```
int maxSubArraySum(int a[], int size) 
{ 
   int max_so_far = 0, max_ending_here = 0; 
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
   { 
       max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i]; 
       if (max_ending_here < 0) 
           max_ending_here = 0; 

       /* Do not compare for all elements. Compare only    
          when  max_ending_here > 0 */
       else if (max_so_far < max_ending_here) 
           max_so_far = max_ending_here; 
   } 
   return max_so_far; 
}
```

My question is how do we find this code's complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity is of O(n) because we don't count every single detail one by one (assignment operators,Subtractions etc) and add it to the complexity as i thought.
We rather count the operations very generally.In this case the loop is our complexity.The loop happens for n times (where n is the amount of elements in our array) thus-->O(n) complexity.
The non loop operations, the small details as i said are of -->O(1) complexity

And so T(n)=O(1)+O(n)=O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Given 'n' the dimension of your size input, in your case the time complexity is O(n^2) as you are iterating on the size n times with a for cycle. The other operations are done in a constant time O(n), for this reason they are trascurable for the whole time complexity.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that's O(n^2). For a size of `n`, it iterates `n` times. The non-loop operations are indeed in constant time, but that's O(1).